# how to parse json objects into tablayout

Tags: android

while i am parsing the json data into tablayout is comming but i am getting empty tab infront of data

```
private void categoryurl() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://godigitalpath.com/app/knn/category.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                // Toast.makeText(Books.this, ""+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               for (i = 1; i <=jsonObject.length(); i++) {
                    Log.e(TAG, " Categorylist:" + jsonObject);

                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i));

                    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(jsonObject1.getString("category")));
                }
                ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), jsonObject);
                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                //  CategoryListAdapter listAdapter = new CategoryListAdapter(MainActivity.this, categoriesTab);
                //recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

And `FragmentPagerAdapter`

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
   private  JSONObject jsonObject;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, JSONObject jsonObject) {
    super(manager);
    this.jsonObject= jsonObject;
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {

    return PoliticalFragment.getInstance(i);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return jsonObject.length();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int i) {
    try {
        return jsonObject.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i)).getString("category");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: You mean tableLayout?